# How to define v-model property to a dynamically object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-model

I'm building a dynamic form that lets the user add more fields by clicking on a button ("adicionar condição"). like the print screen:
[image]

Every row of this form is based on this data:

```
groups: [
  {
    connective: 'and',
    conditions: [
      {
        type: 'lead_prop',
        field: 'tags',
        condition: 'has',
        value: ''
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When the user presses the "adicionar condição" button, a new object is pushed to the conditions array, like this:

```
<v-btn @click="addCondition(i)">Adicionar condição</v-btn>

addCondition(index) {
      this.groups[index].conditions.push({
        type: 'lead_prop',
        field: 'tags',
        condition: 'has',
        value: ''
      });
    }
```

As you can see, I'm using vuetify autocomplete and here is the problem. Every time I add a new condition object to the conditions array of the group, it looks like the v-model of the autocomplete component is the same. If I change the value of the new autocomplete, the previous gets the same value, like this:
[image]

If I change the "tags" field, all the autocompletes existing receive that value too. That is how I'm binding the autocomplete model:

```
   <v-autocomplete
    v-model="g.conditions[index].value"
    :items="tags"
    :teste="index"
    :loading="isLoading"
    :search-input.sync="search"
    color="white"
    hide-no-data
    hide-selected
    item-text="tag"
    item-value="id"
    label="Tags"
    placeholder="Comece a digitar para procurar"
    prepend-icon="mdi-tag"
    return-object>
```

How can I bind every tags autocomplete field to It's object in the conditions array?

This is how I'm iterating over the data:

```
<v-card v-for="(g, i) in groups" :key="i">
<v-row v-for="(c, index) in g.conditions" :key="index">
```

Comment: Could you include the code that defines `g` and `index`? It looks like you may not be looping over the `conditions` correctly.

Comment: @skirtle I'll do this now

Comment: Try `v-model="c.value"` instead. I'd avoid referencing array elements by index in your templates whenever possible

Comment: All the autocompletes keep changing its value to the same of the selected @Phil

Comment: It is funny that this only happens to the autocomplete input. The "contém" and "Não contém" that can see in the figure keep his own value.

Comment: Just looking for clues now but you have a discrepancy between the value you're passing to `v-autocomplete` and the value it is returning. Your initial `value` properties are strings but you're asking the component to return an object (via `return-object`). You should try to be consistent

Comment: I think that's the reason why the selected options It's been stored as object in the value property of the condition, but I don't know if its related to the problem of all autocompletes been binding to the first condition always

Comment: What's the `:teste="index"` prop for?

Comment: I just wanted to see the index value... already removed

Comment: I think I'll have to replace the autocomplete with a normal select, this will be ok until I have a big list of tags

Answer (score 0):

one way to go about this is to create a light component that has the autcomplete inside
then exposed the property to change the model.